# How do I get the bearer token claims that azure b2c promises?

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-ad-b2c

### Background

I have two applications registered in azure, one is a web-based client and the other is a web-based service. The setup is similar to the example found here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi

The user logs in to the client via azure b2c, and then the client queries against the service, authenticated via azure b2c, to obtain its data.

### The Problem

The service is not receiving the expected claims in the bearer token.

### Specifics

Azure B2C *says* that the claims you select for a given policy will be included in "a token", which I assumed would be the bearer token. Below is a screencapture of some of the claims I have selected.
[image: claims for my signup-or-signin policy]

However, on the service when I extract the claims from the bearer token, I get none of the promised claims. Instead, I get the claims shown below.
[image: actual claims received]

I am using `UseOAuthBearerAuthentication` identical to the example provided by microsoft on github (linked above).

Am I missing something?
How do I get the claims that b2c promises?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Application Claims are included in the id_token, not the access_token (*aka bearer token*)**.

This means that the `Select application claims` will allow your client application (native app or web app) to access these custom claims.

**If you want to access custom claims from your back-end service, you'll need to [call the Azure AD Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet)** using the client credentials flow and call the user endpoint like so:

```
https://graph.windows.net/<yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com>/users/<userId>
```

And retrieve the property with the following format:

```
extension_<b2c-extensions-app_appId>_<customAttributeName>
```

For example:

```
extension_e5bf5a2db0c9415cb62661a70d8f0a68_MyCustomAttribute
```

You can obtain the id of your B2C tenant's b2c-extensions-app via the Graph as well:

```
https://graph.windows.net/<yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com>/applications?$filter=displayName eq 'b2c-extensions-app'
```

See this post for more info:
[Moving Azure AD B2C custom user attributes across new environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44496911/moving-azure-ad-b2c-custom-user-attributes-across-new-environments)

Comment: Okay. @Saca, I see the `id_token` being passed to the client, but I am guessing that current libraries do not support passing that token on through to the back-end service, and I don't have time to roll my own support for that. For the graph, do you recommend using `Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.ActiveDirectoryClient`, or should I use something else?

Comment: I couldn't find extensionProperties anywhere in the User object returned by ActiveDirectoryClient, so my hunch would be, no, you have to resort to making the HTTP calls directly.